# Multiple choice A , B, C , D ,E and displaying the output all together

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

Im trying to make a quiz program in java but the answersheet does not work and does not match the user inputted answer. I cantt figure out what's wrong really. Thanks.

My Code :

```
    String [][] x = new String [10][1];
        x [0][0] = "1+2";
        x [1][0] = "1+3";   
        x [2][0] = "1+4";
        x [3][0] = "1+5";       
        x [4][0] = "1+6";
        x [5][0] = "1+7";
        x [6][0] = "1+8";
        x [7][0] = "1+9";
        x [8][0] = "1+10";
        x [9][0] = "1+11";
        int count = 0;
        String[] answersheet= {"b","d","a","a","c","a","a","d","b","b"};
        String user  = "";






        for (int y = 0 ; y < 1 ; y++) {
             for (int z = 0 ; z < 10 ; z++) {
            System.out.print(" "+x[z][y]);
            user = console.next(); 

    }        
             for (int y1 = 0; y1 < 10; y1++){
                 count= count + 1;
            if (user.equals(answersheet[y1])){
                 System.out.println("Q" +count+ " Is correct ");
            }else
                System.out.println("Q "+count+ "is Wrong ");

        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of having a 2d array if all the `Array`s are just one element?

Comment: You are printing all questions, but only store the last answer in 'user'. I think you should use an array or something similar for storing the answers as well.

Comment: Thank You! Finally done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String user is storing only the last value. Make user as a String array and store the user inputs then compare with your answer sheet.